# Present perfect vs. past simple (hidden meaning)

Tags: meaning

It is known that present perfect is used when it is actual for somebody now. So, my examples with possible meanings:

> I lost my key last week. (Meaning: at now it is not my problem. I have another one.)

>

> Ben went home ten minutes ago. (Hidden meaning: at now I don’t await him. I can do my hobby, for example.)
>
> I have lost my key. (Meaning: at now it is my problem. I don’t have another one.)
>
> Ben has gone home. (Hidden meaning: I miss him. I think about him, for example.)

Am I right with possible meanings?

Comment: Would you please give some more detailed context? This [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/124924/109190) is quite similar to yours and demonstrates how a context help learners to understand the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading too much into this.

> I lost the key to my car and took the bus home.

The loss occurred at an indefinite time in the past, and it is not specified whether or not the key has yet been replaced. But whether or not I now have keys is **irrelevant** to the topic of the sentence. We do use the present perfect when we want to indicate that a past action has present **relevance** to the topic. But it goes too far too say that use of the simple past denies present relevance to any topic imaginable.

The problem with grammatical examples is that they do not occur in a context. Thus, it is easy to construe them in a somewhat broader sense that was intended. Moreover the simple past and present perfect differ in other respects.

> Ben went home ten minutes ago

contains a definite specification of time, namely "ten minutes ago." That definite specification requires the simple past, but is silent on present relevance to any topic other than the timing of the event.

> Ben has already gone home

contains an indefinite specification of time, namely "already." It is usual to use the present perfect here because the contrast is between **completed** action in the indefinite past on the one hand and incomplete action in the present or action in the indefinite future. In these time marked cases, the present perfect shows a **perfected aspect,** meaning completed. It is silent on any other topic.

In summary, the present perfect is sometimes used to indicate present relevance, but, sadly, the situation is more complicated because the present perfect has other uses.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks. There is no overtone here. Ok.

Comment: Re *"...broader sense that was intended"*: Do you mean *"...broader sense than was intended"*?

Comment: Jeff, could you answer on a small question? 

Am I right that these sentences are possible in use in one phrase and that the signification of the phrase is definitely clearly?

    I have seen Paula lately. I saw Paula yesterday. I don`t know where is Paula.

Thanks.

Comment: @Sergey I am always happy to respond to questions that I feel competent to answer, but comments are not a good place to do so due to restrictions on length and formatting. And here there seem to be six questions. I suggest starting a new thread. Furthermore, the questions  are not clear. A phrase is a **part** of a sentence so sentences cannot be part of one phrase. As for your three examples, are you asking whether they are consistent when considered together or whether each is unambiguous judged as a seperate sentence?

Comment: Jeff, a new thread was started here. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241262/present-perfect-past-simple-and-present-simple-in-one-phrase-at-once?noredirect=1#comment456191_241262

Comment: I have Kate`s answer. If you may to add smth, you are welcome.

Comment: Kate's answer is, as usual, quite good. I have nothing of importance to add.

Answer (score 3):

Present perfect is used for something that happened at an unspecified time in the past and it has some effect to the present.

> I have lost my keys

This means that I am still without keys.

Simple past is used for something that happened at a specified time in the past

> I lost my keys last week

It does not give any information about the current situation-whether your key is still lost or whether you now have a replacement.

The only one of your example sentences where your interpretation is correct is

> I have lost my key. (Meaning: at now it is my problem. I don`t have an other one.)

For all of the others, you are reading too much into them.