# Present Perfect, Past Simple and Present Simple in one phrase at once

Tags: phrase-usage

Am I right that these sentences are possible in use in one phrase and that the signification of the phrase is definitely clearly?

> I have seen Paula lately. I saw Paula yesterday. I don`t know where Paula is.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be "I don`t know where  Paula is".

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Are you asking whether all three sentences can be used together? For some reason, _lately_ is usually used in a negative sense - 'I haven't seen Paula lately.' You could say "I have seen Paula recently - in fact, I saw her yesterday - but I don't know where she is today."